# How to cut a set of characters in a stringbuilder?

Tags: string, stringbuilder

Is there a way to split a set of characters in a stringbuilder - for example if I have "One Two Three Four" is there a way of getting each individual word which I could then put into a list (using a foreach loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no direct way to split StringBuilder to an array, you need convert to String first, like this:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("One Two Three Four");
    String[] myArray = sb.toString().split(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

for java

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("One Two Three Four");
String[] words = sb.toString().split("[\\s]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

please try using the below mentioned code. Hope it helps you in your task :

```
    //Create Stringbuilder

        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
        strb.Append("One Two Three Four");

        // Convert Stringbuilder to string
        string a = strb.ToString();

        // Split the string based on seprator. Here seprator is space " "
        string[] str = a.Split();

        List<string> al1 = new List<string>();          

        // Add the word of splited string to a string List
        foreach (string str1 in str)
        {
            al1.Add(str1);
        }
```